# You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory

Tags: sass, koala

Using Koala and started using it by adding the 'css' directory. My directory structure looks like

```
-- www
-- -- css
-- -- -- template.css
-- -- -- template.scss
```

I've checked 'compass mode' in Koala but it is giving error 'You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory'.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error and resolved it by editing the Koala project settings.

In Koala, right click on your project's folder, follow the menu for Project Settings > New Settings > For SASS

Koala will ask if you want to create a `koala-config.json`. Answer, yes. Unless this file already exists. In that case go directly to editing it.

Edit the section of `koala-config.json` called Mappings. Keep in mind that `koala-config.json` is in the `my-project-folder` root and the "src" and "dest" values should be relative to that file. So, for me, all my CSS files are in `my-project-folder/assets/css` and I changed the config file as below:

```
// The mappings of source directory and output directory
"mappings": [
     {  
        "src": "assets/css",
        "dest": "assets/css"
     }
],
```

For you, I suspect this should do it:

```
// The mappings of source directory and output directory
"mappings": [
     {  
        "src": "www/css",
        "dest": "www/css"
     }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

The instructions above did not help me.

SOLUTION: I simply changed the NAME of the FOLDER that held my .scss files from scss to sass, deleted the .rb and .json files (if they exist) and reloaded my file to Koala.

I hope it works for you all.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your computer has Ruby installed. Then set projects paths in Koala as @helgatheviking said